# Why surround template parameters with parentheses when `require clause` is surrounded by parentheses?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Why surround template parameters with parentheses when `require clause` is surrounded by parentheses ?

```cpp
template(typename This, typename Receiver)
    (requires same_as<remove_cvref_t<This>, type> AND
      receiver<Receiver> AND
      constructible_from<std::tuple<Values...>, member_t<This, std::tuple<Values...>>>)
friend auto tag_invoke(tag_t<connect>, This&& that, Receiver&& r)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<std::tuple<Values...>, member_t<This, std::tuple<Values...>>>)
    -> operation<Receiver, Values...> {
  return {static_cast<This&&>(that).values_, static_cast<Receiver&&>(r)};
}
```

from [libunifex](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/libunifex/blob/main/include/unifex/just.hpp)

Comment: I don't think that is legit code. Template parameters have to use angle brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why surround template parameters with parentheses when require clause
> is surrounded by parentheses ?

The `template(typename This, typename Receiver)` part you see is actually a macro, [which is defined as](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/libunifex/blob/99b39667e04f6f12ef1bed9a5c69312cc1a9abd3/include/unifex/detail/prologue.hpp#L33):

```
#if UNIFEX_CXX_CONCEPTS
  #define template(...) \
    template <__VA_ARGS__> UNIFEX_PP_EXPAND \
    /**/
#else
  #define template(...) \
    template <__VA_ARGS__ UNIFEX_TEMPLATE_SFINAE_AUX_ \
    /**/
#endif
```

which is used to simplify template definitions with the suffix `UNIFEX_PP_EXPAND`.

Comment: Thanks, so that `template` is a macro name, not [c++ keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template). It seems to be for c++17 compatibility only.

Comment: The goal here is to have templates use concepts if concepts are available, but fallback to using regular C++17 enable-if based constraints if concepts are not available. Otherwise, you could _just_ use enable-if (worse experience for C++20 users) or write the whole code twice (more likely to get it wrong).

Comment: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/f4vcbP1ce)